# Chrome Extension that monitors/verifies whether a transaction has been made on a given website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, web-applications

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Given that there are no Web API's is this a possibility?

I heard that it's possible via the following:

- confirmation page detection
- monitoring network requests
- page event detection
- scraping web data / digital receipt
- raw packet capturing and analysis

However I don't know which one is the best and easiest.

Comment: "However I don't know which one is the best and easiest." - Welcome to Stack Overflow. We hope you have a nice stay! Unfortunately, we also don't know which way is best and easiest, because 1) "best" and "easiest" are usually mutually exclusive 2) We don't know what the "given website" is

Comment: "I heard that it's possible via the following" - Where did you "hear" this? Did you, by any chance, hear it from Mr. ChatGPT?

Comment: Let's say for example Amazon? Also yes ofcourse I used ChatGPT. Fastest way to find solutions. Why wouldn't I? @ThomasMueller